# numeric validation in form in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

forms.py

```
class PhoneForm(forms.ModelForm):

    fields = ['user','name1','number1','name2','number2','name3','number3','emergency','emergency_number']
def clean(self):
        cd=self.cleaned_data
        number1=cd.get('number1')
        number2=cd.get('number2')
        number3=cd.get('number3')

        if (number1.isalpha()):
            raise forms.ValidationError("Please enter a valid phone number")
        return number1

        if(number2.isalpha()): 
            raise forms.ValidationError("Please enter a valid phone number")
        return number2   

        if(number3.isalpha()): 
            raise forms.ValidationError("Please enter a valid phone number")
        return number3
```

template.html

```
            <tr>
                <td>{{PhoneForm.name1}}</td>
                <td>{{PhoneForm.number1}}{{ PhoneForm.number1.errors }}</td>
            </tr>
```

views.py

```
def add_phone(request):

    phoneForm = PhoneForm({'user':request.user}) 
    phone = Phone_info.objects.get(user=request.user)
    phoneForm = PhoneForm(instance=phone) 
    if request.method=='POST':   
        phoneForm = PhoneForm(request.POST,instance=phone)
        if phoneForm.is_valid():
            phone=phoneForm.save(commit=False)
            phone.save()
            return redirect('/member/contact-list/')

    return render_to_response('incident/add_phone.html',
    {
    'about_menu': True,
    'PhoneForm' :phoneForm
    },
    context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Getting the below traceback

```
Traceback:
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/root/Projects/ir/incident/views.py" in add_phone
  634.         if phoneForm.is_valid():
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in is_valid
  121.         return self.is_bound and not bool(self.errors)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in _get_errors
  112.             self.full_clean()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in full_clean
  269.         self._post_clean()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in _post_clean
  308.         self.instance = construct_instance(self, self.instance, opts.fields, opts.exclude)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in construct_instance
  39.                 or not f.name in cleaned_data:

Exception Type: TypeError at /member/add-phone/
Exception Value: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

For validating the phone number field.

Condition is it should take only numeric digits,should not take alphabet or alpha-numeic,the above code not producing any errors not validation is not happening.What went wrong in my code.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you returning the numbers?

Comment: sorry,i removed,but why the validation is not happening

Comment: You could use the inbuilt validators. Use `RegexValidator` against `\d+`. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/#regexvalidator

Comment: Post your view code, and fix your indentation.

Answer (score 3):

This should work. And I'd actively request you to read [the source of `validate_integer()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/validators.py#L75) and see what they did there.

```
from django.core.validators import validate_integer

class PhoneForm(forms.ModelForm):
    fields = ['user','name1','number1','name2','number2','name3','number3','emergency','emergency_number']

    def clean(self):
        cd=self.cleaned_data
        validate_integer(cd.get('number1', None))
        validate_integer(cd.get('number2', None))
        validate_integer(cd.get('number3', None))
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this in your model.py

```
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator

numeric = RegexValidator(r'^[0-9+]', 'Only digit characters.')

class FooModel(models.Model):
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, validators=[numeric])
```

Comment: the regex should be r'^[0-9]+' which means any digit character of any length

Answer (score 2):

Lots of issues here.

Firstly, you should *not* store phone numbers as integers. Integer fields don't allow brackets, dashes, leading zeroes, and all sorts of other things that phone numbers do.

Secondly, your `clean` method must return `self.cleaned_data` at the end, which is the source of your actual problem.

Thirdly, you should do individual field validation in the `clean_FIELDNAME` methods - eg `clean_number1` etc.

Fourthly, if you were actually using integer fields for a good reason, there is no need to validate that they contain integers, because Django does that automatically already. If for some reason your model field is not an integerfield but you still want to validate as an integer, just override the field definition in your form: `number1 = forms.IntegerField()`.

Comment: 5th: if a phone number start with 0 and you store it using an integer field, the leading zero/s (phone number prefix) are lost

Answer (score 0):

For phone numbers you should control number possiblity with accuracy. In example if your phone numbers are similar to **abccccccccc** which **a** is always zero, **b** is not zero and **c** can be any digits while total length is exactly eleven digits.
You should have a regex which start with zero (`^0`) after that one none zero digit (`[1-9]`) and then exactly nine other digits (`\d{9}`) not more (`$`).

```
from django import forms
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    phone_validator = RegexValidator("^0[1-9]\d{9}$")
    mobile = forms.CharField(
        validators=(phone_validator,),)
```